# Save a text file as a dictionary

Tags: python

I am trying to read in the following text file with four columns separated by commas:

```
1, 0.1, 0.2, 73
1, 0.11, 0.1, 101
2, 0.23, 0.01, 17
2, 0.12, 0.15, 23
```

where the first number represents a batch, the second and third represent an x and y coordinate respectively and the fourth is a value.

And I want to save this text file as a dictionary in python. I tried using a save_rows function to create a dictionary:

```
def save_rows('sample1.txt'):

    keys = ['batch', 'x', 'y', 'val']
    dicts = []
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip().split(',')
            d = dict(zip(keys, line))
            return d
            dicts.append(d)
```

But it doesn't return or create an dictionary, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Its not what clear you want?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry if I was unclear. I have now edited the text and hope it is easier to understand what I want. In short, what I want is help with how to successfully save a text file as a dictionary?

Comment: Can you also include your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some issues in your code. Firstly, the function `save_rows` should take an argument like `filename` and then you need to pass the name of your file below in your code. For example `save_rows("sample1.txt")` passes `sample1.txt` as the argument for `filename` in the function. Secondly, you have used `return` keyword at the wrong place. I would advise you to have a look at [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_return.asp) to clearly understand what `return` does. `return` needs to be used at the very end to print out the list called `dicts` which contains all the dictionaries for the 4 rows. When you correct those two issues, your program will work fine. Below is an example of how your code should look like.

```
def save_rows(filename):
    keys = ['batch', 'x', 'y', 'val']
    dicts = []
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip().split(',')
            d = dict(zip(keys, line))
            dicts.append(d)
    return dicts

print(save_rows("sample1.txt"))
```

The output that I got is as follows.

```
[{'batch': '1', 'x': ' 0.1', 'y': ' 0.2', 'val': ' 73'}, {'batch': '1', 'x': ' 0.11', 'y': ' 0.1', 'val': ' 101'}, {'batch': '2', 'x': ' 0.23', 'y': ' 0.01', 'val': ' 17'}, {'batch': '2', 'x': ' 0.12', 'y': ' 0.15', 'val': ' 23'}]
```